# cmake doesn't work in windows XP

Tags: windows, configuration, cmake

I'm new with `cmake`,just installed it and following this article:

http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~adanner/tips/cmake.php

```
D:\Works\c\cmake\build>cmake ..
-- Building for: NMake Makefiles
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  To use the NMake generator, cmake must be run from a shell that can use the
  compiler cl from the command line.  This environment does not contain
  INCLUDE, LIB, or LIBPATH, and these must be set for the cl compiler to
  work.


-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Warning at D:/Tools/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/Platform/Windows-cl.cmake:32 (ENABLE_LANGUAGE):
  To use the NMake generator, cmake must be run from a shell that can use the
  compiler cl from the command line.  This environment does not contain
  INCLUDE, LIB, or LIBPATH, and these must be set for the cl compiler to
  work.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  D:/Tools/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:58 (INCLUDE)
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


CMake Error: your RC compiler: "CMAKE_RC_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_RC_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
-- Check for CL compiler version
-- Check for CL compiler version - failed
-- Check if this is a free VC compiler
-- Check if this is a free VC compiler - yes
-- Using FREE VC TOOLS, NO DEBUG available
-- Check for working C compiler: cl
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
  To use the NMake generator, cmake must be run from a shell that can use the
  compiler cl from the command line.  This environment does not contain
  INCLUDE, LIB, or LIBPATH, and these must be set for the cl compiler to
  work.


CMake Warning at D:/Tools/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/Platform/Windows-cl.cmake:32 (ENABLE_LANGUAGE):
  To use the NMake generator, cmake must be run from a shell that can use the
  compiler cl from the command line.  This environment does not contain
  INCLUDE, LIB, or LIBPATH, and these must be set for the cl compiler to
  work.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  D:/Tools/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:58 (INCLUDE)
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT)


CMake Error at D:/Tools/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeRCInformation.cmake:22 (GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  D:/Tools/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/Platform/Windows-cl.cmake:32 (ENABLE_LANGUAGE)
  D:/Tools/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:58 (INCLUDE)
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: CMAKE_RC_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: your C compiler: "cl" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_C_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Check for working C compiler: cl -- broken
CMake Error at D:/Tools/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (MESSAGE):
  The C compiler "cl" is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


CMake Error: your C compiler: "cl" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_C_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "cl" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

What are the complete requirement to use `cmake` successfully in windows XP?I've already installed Visual Studio under `D:\Tools\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0`

Comment: Luckily there are better options for build DSL languages for .NET now, like a library called FAKE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, I have to confess that I don't know **cmake**.

> To use the NMake generator, cmake
>   must be run from a shell that can use
>   the   compiler cl from the command
>   line.  This environment does not
>   contain   INCLUDE, LIB, or LIBPATH,
>   and these must be set for the cl
>   compiler to   work.

The error above means that the proper locations to your C/C++ compiler's headers and libraries could not be found by cmake.

Instead of running cmake from the Command Prompt, try running cmake from the **Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt**. You can find it under  *Start > Programs > Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 > Visual Studio Tools*) or *vcvarsall.bat* in the folder *Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC*. The visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt should set all these environment variables for you automatically so that cmake knows where to find the necessary files that it needs.

The Command Prompt will start in your Visual Studio folder, so you'll have to type the following commands to switch to your source folder and start cmake.

```
D:
cd D:\Works\c\cmake\build>
cmake
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues on Win7, and was getting the same error - The C compiler "cl.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program.

The solution that worked for me :

1. On Windows Donot run cmake on the cygwin terminal.
2. Run it from the command prompt, AND also ensure that you have admin rights, In windows 7 you can start command prompt as administrator by going to Start->All programs->Accessories-> (Right Click on Command Prompt) and Select "Run as administrator"

Then run `'cmake <your source>'` Worked like a charm for me.