# Can't build a Makefile with CMAKE, compiler is not specified

Tags: c, windows, opencv, makefile, cmake

i'm trying to use OpenCV for Java Desktop(Available since 02/15/2013) to do a simple face recognition project(for study purposes), and i'm having a problem to build the OpenCV in Windows.

I'm following this [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.4-beta/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html) , 
and i got stuck in the build part, where you need to generate a Makefile.

I executed the command below(as the tutorial says):

`cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF`

and got the following error:

```
Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags:

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado(System couldn't find the specified file).

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado(System couldn't find the specified file) 

Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado(System couldn't find the specified file).

Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado(System couldn't find the specified file).

Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -Aa

The output was:
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado(System couldn't find the specified file).

Determining if the CXX compiler works failed with the following output:
```

I'm a newbie in C, but i think it might be a problem with my compiler, i have MinGW installed, but i don't know how to specify to CMake where he is.

I also tried to run the CMake GUI, but it returned the same error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101456/running-cmake-on-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to specify to CMake where the MinGW is, since it is in PATH environment variable. 
If you want to install OpenCV 2.4.4 with support for Java Desktop, you do not need to compile all source, just download executable from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.4.4/) (also specified in tutorial that you mentioned) and extract it to the directory where you want to install it. And that is it.

Compiling Opencv for Java was necessary in previous version, when it was experimental.

Comment: Thank you very much Andriy, i was still having trouble with eclipse environment, the sample code was throwing an exception, even if i included the jar to the project. The problem was the .dll file. Again, i thank you.