# can't compile with cmake

Tags: c++, c

After a few hours getting errors i need some help.
I'm trying to compile duke, source can be found here:
http://opensource.mikrosimage.eu/duke.html

I downloaded Cmake (I've never compiled anything else then python files to pyc) so very new territory for me.

This is from the error log:

```
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler:  
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler:  
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified
```

I have cmake in my PATH variable, using win 7 x64, i also tried to put in the path to modules and compilers but still i'm getting these error.

So do i have to download the compilers seperate or what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: cmake is not a compiler. So yes, you do need to get a compiler.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't build a Makefile with CMAKE, compiler is not specified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341019/cant-build-a-makefile-with-cmake-compiler-is-not-specified)

Answer (score 0):

From the INSTALL.md file:

> For the moment Duke can compile on Linux only. The MacOs version is on its way and the Windows version is untested
>   and will probably not compile as of now. We expect to support those three platforms in a near future.

And:

> You'll need a C++11 compiler, Duke is known to compile on GCC 4.7.1 and later.

If you are feeling very brave, you could install [Cygwin](http://cygwin.org/) which does offer a C++ compiler and try the build from a Cygwin terminal.