# Compiling Google test with Mingw-w64

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest, mingw-w64

I'm trying to compile Google Test with Mingw-w64 in a Windows 10 machine but I always get the error:

```
C:\git\tdd\googletest>cmake CMakeLists.txt -G "MinGW Makefiles"
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MinGW Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MinGW Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

This is is what I'm doing:

1. Open a Windows CMD terminal and change folder t where I downloaded google test
2. Add CMake, make and g++ to the path `set PATH="C:\Program Files\CMake\bin";"C:\msys\bin";"C:\Program Files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\bin";%PATH%`
3. Run CMake with `cmake CMakeLists.txt -G "MinGW Makefiles"`

These are the versions of the tools:

```
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i686-pc-msys
```

- cmake version 3.15.3
- g++ (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0

Make comes from the [MSYS package from Mingw-64w](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/External%20binary%20packages%20%28Win64%20hosted%29/MSYS%20%2832-bit%29/). I cloned Google Test from [here](https://github.com/google/googletest.git)

Any help is much appreciated!

### EDIT 1

None of the solutions in [CMake/MinGW unknown compilers, gcc.exe broken](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50345608/6271889) work.

### EDIT 2

I also tried using environment variables to tell CMake which tools to use.

1. Added the tools' folders to the PATH:

`set PATH="C:\Program Files\CMake\bin";"C:\Program Files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\bin";%PATH%`

2. Calling CMake with

`cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/gcc" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/g++" -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/mingw32-make.exe" CMakeLists.txt -G "MinGW Makefiles"`

I get this error:

```
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (project):
  The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

    C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/gcc

  is not a full path to an existing compiler tool.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
  the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (project):
  The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

    C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/g++

  is not a full path to an existing compiler tool.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/git/tdd/googletest/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/git/tdd/googletest/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

As g++ and gcc are in the PATH, I also tried to call CMake like so:

`cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="gcc" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="g++" -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="mingw32-make.exe" CMakeLists.txt -G "MinGW Makefiles"`

Which yields the same error as the previous try:

```
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (project):
  The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

    gcc

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
  the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (project):
  The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

    g++

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/git/tdd/googletest/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/git/tdd/googletest/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

However, I *CAN* call `g++`:

```
C:\git\tdd\googletest>g++
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original problems stem from the choice of using *make.exe* for MSYS2
together with the MinGW-w64 compiler, which is not supported by that version of *make.exe*. The correct program to use with MinGW-w64 is *mingw32-make.exe*, which is part of the MinGW-w64 distribution. I am not fully able to follow your later edits, but for instance this works perfectly well in *cmd.exe*:

```
set "PATH=C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;%PATH%"
set "PATH=C:\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin;%PATH%"

cmake ^
    -G "MinGW Makefiles" ^
    -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc.exe ^
    -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++.exe ^
    -D CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=mingw32-make.exe ^
    .

mingw32-make.exe
```

Here, I used:

- CMake 3.15.2,
- MinGW-w64 8.1.0 ([x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/8.1.0/threads-posix/seh/x86_64-8.1.0-release-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0.7z)),
- and current git revision of Google Test.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I managed to compile it using CMDER's Bash console. Assuming you have Mingw-w64 installed at `C:\mingw-w64\` (**no spaces in the path**), these steps will get you a working Google test library under Mingw-w64

1. Set the PATH to:

`PATH=/c/Program\ Files/CMake/bin:/c/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin:$PATH`

2. Invoke CMake with

`cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++ -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=mingw32-make.exe CMakeLists.txt -G 'MSYS Makefiles'`

3. Build with

`mingw32-make.exe -j8`

I'm gonna go on a limb here and say this probably should work with the Git Bash shell. I still don't have a solution for building it with the regular Windows CMD terminal.