# Compiling cpputest with mingw-w64

Tags: cmake, mingw-w64, cpputest

I'm trying to compile cpputest with mingw-w64 but can't make it work and I can't find any resources on how to do that. So hopefully this question will help others in the future.

I would like to compile cpputest using mingw-w64, preferably without installing MSYS2 or other packages.

I have mingw-w64 i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0 installed. I've cloned cpputest from [here](https://github.com/cpputest/cpputest).

I tried following [Compiling Google test with Mingw-w64](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58793252/6271889) and [Compiling and using CppUTest 3.8 under MSYS2/MinGW32](https://github.com/cpputest/cpputest/issues/1086) by calling CMake with:

```
cmake ^
    -G "MinGW Makefiles" ^
    -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc.exe ^
    -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++.exe ^
    -D CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=mingw32-make.exe ^
    -D C++11=ON ^
    .
```

Which yields:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
CppUTest Version 3.8

Current compiler options:
    CC:                                 C:/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/gcc.exe
    CXX:                                C:/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/g++.exe
    CppUTest CFLAGS:                     -include "C:/git/tdd/cpputest/include/CppUTest/MemoryLeakDetectorMallocMacros.h"  -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -Wswitch-default -Wswitch-enum -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion -Wno-padded -Wno-long-long -Wstrict-prototypes
    CppUTest CXXFLAGS:                   -include "C:/git/tdd/cpputest/include/CppUTest/MemoryLeakDetectorNewMacros.h" -include "C:/git/tdd/cpputest/include/CppUTest/MemoryLeakDetectorMallocMacros.h"    -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -Wswitch-default -Wswitch-enum -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion -Wno-padded -Wno-long-long -Woverloaded-virtual -Wno-old-style-cast -Wno-c++14-compat
    CppUTest LDFLAGS:

Features configured in CppUTest:
    Memory Leak Detection:              ON
    Compiling Extensions:               ON
    Support Long Long:                  OFF
    Use CppUTest flags:                 ON

    Using Standard C library:           ON
    Using Standard C++ library:         ON
    Using C++11 library:                ON

    Generating map file:                OFF
    Compiling with coverage:            OFF

    Compile and run self-tests          ON
    Run self-tests separately           OFF

-------------------------------------------------------
```

Running make fails with:

```
>mingw32-make.exe
Scanning dependencies of target CppUTest
[  1%] Building CXX object src/CppUTest/CMakeFiles/CppUTest.dir/CommandLineArguments.cpp.obj
In file included from C:/git/tdd/cpputest/include/CppUTest/Utest.h:34,
                 from C:/git/tdd/cpputest/include/CppUTest/TestHarness.h:39,
                 from C:\git\tdd\cpputest\src\CppUTest\CommandLineArguments.cpp:29:
C:/git/tdd/cpputest/include/CppUTest/SimpleString.h:183:31: error: 'nullptr_t' does not name a type
 SimpleString StringFrom(const nullptr_t value);
                               ^~~~~~~~~
C:/git/tdd/cpputest/include/CppUTest/SimpleString.h:183:31: note: 'nullptr_t' is defined in header '<cstddef>'; did you forget to '#include <cstddef>'?
C:/git/tdd/cpputest/include/CppUTest/SimpleString.h:42:1:
+#include <cstddef>

C:/git/tdd/cpputest/include/CppUTest/SimpleString.h:183:31:
 SimpleString StringFrom(const nullptr_t value);
                               ^~~~~~~~~
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [src\CppUTest\CMakeFiles\CppUTest.dir\build.make:63: src/CppUTest/CMakeFiles/CppUTest.dir/CommandLineArguments.cpp.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:886: src/CppUTest/CMakeFiles/CppUTest.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:140: all] Error 2
```

I tried the obvious solution of adding cstddef to SimpleString.h:

```c
--- a/include/CppUTest/SimpleString.h                                                
+++ b/include/CppUTest/SimpleString.h                                                
@@ -180,6 +180,9 @@ SimpleString BracketsFormattedHexString(SimpleString hexString); 
  * Specifically nullptr_t is not officially supported                               
  */                                                                                 
 #if __cplusplus > 199711L && !defined __arm__                                       
+                                                                                    
+#include <cstddef>                                                                  
+                                                                                    
 SimpleString StringFrom(const nullptr_t value);                                     
 #endif
```

But that still fails with the same error.

So I tried following [Build error with CMake and MSYS2 mingw-w64](https://github.com/cpputest/cpputest/issues/669) by installing MSYS2 and then mingw-w64, CMake and Ninja. That gives:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
CppUTest Version 3.8

Current compiler options:
    CC:                                 C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/cc.exe
    CXX:                                C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/c++.exe
    CppUTest CFLAGS:                     -include "C:/git/tdd/cpputest/include/CppUTest/MemoryLeakDetectorMallocMacros.h"  -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -Wswitch-default -Wswitch-enum -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion -Wno-padded -Wno-long-long -Wstrict-prototypes
    CppUTest CXXFLAGS:                   -include "C:/git/tdd/cpputest/include/CppUTest/MemoryLeakDetectorNewMacros.h" -include "C:/git/tdd/cpputest/include/CppUTest/MemoryLeakDetectorMallocMacros.h"  -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -Wswitch-default -Wswitch-enum -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion -Wno-padded -Wno-long-long -Woverloaded-virtual -Wno-old-style-cast
    CppUTest LDFLAGS:

Features configured in CppUTest:
    Memory Leak Detection:              ON
    Compiling Extensions:               ON
    Support Long Long:                  OFF
    Use CppUTest flags:                 ON

    Using Standard C library:           ON
    Using Standard C++ library:         ON
    Using C++11 library:                OFF

    Generating map file:                OFF
    Compiling with coverage:            OFF

    Compile and run self-tests          ON
    Run self-tests separately           OFF

-------------------------------------------------------
```

Compiling with `cmake -G Ninja . && ninja` fails with:

```
include/CppUTest/SimpleString.h:183:31:
 SimpleString StringFrom(const nullptr_t value);
                               ^~~~~~~~~
[10/98] Building CXX object src/CppUTest/CMakeFiles/CppUTest.dir/TestMemoryAllocator.cpp.obj
FAILED: src/CppUTest/CMakeFiles/CppUTest.dir/TestMemoryAllocator.cpp.obj
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\c++.exe  -DCPPUTEST_HAVE_STRDUP=1 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -D_TIMESPEC_DEFINED=1 -I. -Iinclude -Isrc/CppUTest/../../include -include "C:/git/tdd/cpputest/include/CppUTest/MemoryLeakDetectorNewMacros.h" -include "C:/git/tdd/cpputest/include/CppUTest/MemoryLeakDetectorMallocMacros.h"  -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -Wswitch-default -Wswitch-enum -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion -Wno-padded -Wno-long-long -Woverloaded-virtual -Wno-old-style-cast -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -MD -MT src/CppUTest/CMakeFiles/CppUTest.dir/TestMemoryAllocator.cpp.obj -MF src\CppUTest\CMakeFiles\CppUTest.dir\TestMemoryAllocator.cpp.obj.d -o src/CppUTest/CMakeFiles/CppUTest.dir/TestMemoryAllocator.cpp.obj -c src/CppUTest/TestMemoryAllocator.cpp
In file included from include/CppUTest/Utest.h:34,
                 from include/CppUTest/TestHarness.h:39,
                 from src/CppUTest/TestMemoryAllocator.cpp:28:
include/CppUTest/SimpleString.h:183:31: error: 'nullptr_t' does not name a type
 SimpleString StringFrom(const nullptr_t value);
                               ^~~~~~~~~
include/CppUTest/SimpleString.h:183:31: note: 'nullptr_t' is defined in header '<cstddef>'; did you forget to '#include <cstddef>'?
include/CppUTest/SimpleString.h:42:1:
+#include <cstddef>

include/CppUTest/SimpleString.h:183:31:
 SimpleString StringFrom(const nullptr_t value);
                               ^~~~~~~~~
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this was a bug in CppUtest.

```
@@ -562,7 +562,7 @@ SimpleString BracketsFormattedHexString(SimpleString hexString)
   * Specifically nullptr_t is not officially supported
   */
   #if __cplusplus > 199711L && !defined __arm__
 - SimpleString StringFrom(const nullptr_t value)
 + SimpleString StringFrom(const std::nullptr_t value)
   {
       (void) value;
       return "(null)";
```

It's fixed since Dec. 5th, 2019.

https://github.com/leonardopsantos/cpputest/commit/cb8c457dda6741ede7009103db99967b5f27c969