# How to use cmake build on windows using mingw(gcc g++ on windows)?

Tags: gcc, cmake, mingw

The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.1.0

```
Run Build Command(s):nmake -f Makefile cmTC_6c5fa/fast && 系统找不到指定的文件。
Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: nmake -f Makefile cmTC_6c5fa/fast &&
```

CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)

Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "W:/cl/primecount/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "W:/cl/primecount/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

Comment: Please, describe your actions and commands entered. If you truly want to build the project in MinGW, then you need to specify proper generator, like in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4101496/3440745).

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `nmake` for MinGW builds.

Tell `cmake` to use MinGW makefiles with the `-G"MinGW Makefiles"` so the build uses `mingw32-make` instead of `nmake`.

There are even some alternatives:

If you use MSYS shell instead you can also use `-G"MSYS Makefiles"` to use MSYS' `make`.

If you want faster builds and you have [Ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) available you can also use `-GNinja` to build with `ninja`.