# CMake microsoft visual studio + gcc

Tags: gcc, cmake, visual-studio-2019

I'm using cmake to build the project.
There is a CMakeLists where is used to build the project.

So, when I create a build folder, and use

cmake ..

the project solution is created, but with MVSC c++ compiler.

Is it possible to generate a solution with GCC compiler but in a Visual studio solution?

Comment: Does this work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101456/running-cmake-on-windows ?

Comment: this makes the MinGW structure, but I want MSVC .sln with GCC compiler, the  The C compiler identification and the CXX compiler identification

Comment: Have you tried [usual ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45934279/3440745) for setting compiler in CMake? E.g. pass to `cmake` additional options `-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=</path/to/c/compiler>` and `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=</path/to/c++/compiler>`.