# Zlib Installation - mingw compiler

Tags: c++, mingw, zlib

I just downloaded Zlib's source code from the website -> https://zlib.net/

```
 zlib source code, version 1.2.11, zipfile format ....
   -  US (zlib.net)
```

And I'm struggling with setting up this library, So I'm trying to get some help from some experienced people. And an example will be helpful for me to start with.

I'm using `gcc 8.1.0`, `windows`.

Thanks!

Comment: You never mentioned what, *specifically* is the problem. If it is a build issue, imho the easiest way to build zlib on *any* platform is via cmake. It really is the cat's pajamas (for a LOT of things, including that).

Comment: ***I'm struggling with setting up this library*** what issues are you facing?

Comment: I'm trying to build the zlib library but I don't know what to exactly do

Comment: Assuming you have mingw properly installed, configured, and the bin folder in your windows PATH correctly, using cmake for the build is [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101456/running-cmake-on-windows)

Comment: You could switch to have msys2 provide your mingw and use the msys2 package manager download and install a compatible zlib for you with little effort. [https://www.msys2.org/](https://www.msys2.org/) and [https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-zlib?repo=mingw64](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-zlib?repo=mingw64) the install command is `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-zlib` from the mingw64 terminal. msys also comes with a newer mingw with gcc-11.2

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: already solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the steps I use:

1. open cmd.exe
2. type `sh`
   You should see a prompt like that:

   sh-3.1$
3. once in sh, change dir to your lib dir., so for me is:

   *cd /c/Users/ing.conti/Documents/zlib1211/zlib-1.2.11/*
4. when there, you should ber allowed to call ./configure
   You should see a message saying:

"Please use win32/Makefile.gcc instead." if so:

5. type:

   *make -fwin32/Makefile.gcc; make test testdll -fwin32/Makefile.gcc*

as per readme for windows.

You should see:

[image]

Now their tests run fine.

6. You will see a bunch of *.o and *.exe inside.
   (delete manually if You want to see recompiling again, OR use:
   make clean -fwin32/Makefile.gcc)

You can run *.exe BOTH from "sh" AND from cmd line of windows.

Now You can start modifying sources and / or Makefile.gcc, or duplicate it....

Comment: i mentioned that i'm using mingw and windows

Comment: yes, mingw gcc.

Comment: I did install mingw for windows and gcc compile ita part form setting path and all the  specific settings for windows (PATH..... all dirs... and oer...)

Comment: what do you mean? btw typing ```./configure``` in the ```zlib_dir``` gives me ```The term './configure' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program.```

Comment: this question was posted days ago, and you helped me a lot.
Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. feel free to write to my email if You need further tips.